poor man's reflection for Rust
I am looking to either use an existing crate or implement a "poor man's" reflection for rust.  In particular, rather than trying to reflect struct fields, as many crates appear to do, am looking to call functions by name and with a vector of typed parameters.
In my configuration files I often define which implementation of an interface (Trait) I want to apply for a given application, for example
"behavior": "FooBarBehavior(1.23, 31)",

This ctor specification would be parsed yielding a name "FooBarBehavior" and a Vec<Box> containing the parameters in the appropriate type.  In C++ made use of variadic templates to declare a type-safe mapping between a named class.  The registration was provided as follows, one for each class:
    ((new Class<FooBarBehavior>("FooBarBehavior"))
        ->ctor<const vector<int>&, int>()
        ->ctor<double, int>()
    ),

The above would register "FooBarBehavior" and create 2 mappings between a vector of arguments and the ctor, noting the types and providing the variadic creation machinery.
I recognize that Rust has powerful macros, so wondering what would be the best way to:

register "new" creation functions
create code to map between a vector of typed arguments to the actual ctor (function) call

I am new to Rust, though happy to dig deep, so appreciate pointers.

This sounds like a case for an enum, one variant for each function that can be called. Rust doesn't really have a way to "register" stuff at global scope from multiple locations, even using macros, unless you wrap the entire crate module in a macro. However, macros would be a good way to generate the glue functions that handle parsing the arguments and invoking the backing function. It goes without saying that each function must return a value of exactly the same type (which could be a boxed trait object).

What you could probably do is write a proc macro that will expand to the enum implementation. The macro would need to take as input the list of backing functions and the number of arguments each one takes. The argument types themselves need not be specified, but the argument types would have to implement FromStr. Then generating the code for each enum variant is trivial.

Procedural macros in Rust are quite hard I think if you are new to Rust, so I would suggest starting by writing all the code by hand, to make sure that you properly design the code; and then try to leverage macros to automate all that code writing. This way, you'll decouple the difficulty of learning Rust, and the difficulty of learning procedural macros.

As already said here, you are using an overly complex tool for the job. Write simple ADTs describing your config and derive serde for them, then implement a serde deserializer for your config format (if there isn't an existing one already).

Regarding derive serde, not looking to deserialize here, rather call ctors which may take references to other types forming an efficient expression tree.   I may have expressions in configuration like:   Max(Foo(1.2, Bar(3.4,1)), Baz(...)); The ctor values that Foo, Bar, Baz, Max, take are defined by the type's ctor parameters;  The parser would use meta data collected to determine the appropriate types to pack into the any vector and dispatch appropriately.
It seems like a proc macro, evaluating the ctor AST's, and generating code to dispatch and "register" would work.

I see that serde could be used if there is a reasonable 1:1 between what one wants a ctor to do vs struct fields.  In my C++ implementation have fuzzy matching and value conversion for the ctors so would have to experiment with how that could possibly be implemented with serde.
Thanks for the pointers, all.
